# Django: Show different content based on User

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-templates, django-views

I'd like to create a school management system for my personal project.

Let's say there is an Admin for every School. But there is some Admin that can manage more than one schools, and they can switch between schools to manage each school.

I've thought one way to do it, by using different URL path eg.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(schools/<int:pk>/, SchoolView.as_view()),
]
```

Is there a way so I do not separate by using different URL path for each schools? So, each Admin get similar URL path, but the view render or filter to use different school, based on the Admin.

But I don't really know how to do that? Can I get an advice how to do it. Many thanks!

Comment: I personally think your approach is a good one by having a reference in your URL to the current school being administered, as long as you make sure you check that a user has permission to edit that school before redirecting them to its admin page, and this could be easily done by means of a decorator instead of repeating code on each view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every view function accepts a `request` parameter, so wherever you define your view function it would probably look like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    #you can check user here with request.user
    #example
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render('your_template_for_admin.html', {})
    return render('your_template_for_basic_user.html', {})
```

**EDIT:** If you're using a class based view then you can override it's **get** method like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #here you can access the request object
        return render('template.html', {})
```

**Edit based on comment**: You can use [get_context_data()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) instead of `get()` as @Daniel Roseman stated in comments.

```
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #example code assuming that we have a relation between schools and admin A
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['schools'] = School.objects.filter(admin_id=self.request.user__id)
        return context
```

And then you can use `schools` queryset in your template.

Comment: Yes. This is a good answer for those who want to separate **Admin** and **Normal User**. But my question is how to filter/render different object from view. The template is the same, but the content is different. Example: Admin A manage School A and School B. With the same url path (eg. 127.0.0.1), they would get a different school, based on their choosing

Comment: Updated, hope this helps! :)

Comment: You should not override `get` (or `post`) in class-based views. Rather, override the relevant method - `get_queryset` or `get_context_data`.

Comment: But how should he get the current logged user in `get_queryset` or `get_context_data` as if they don't pass a `request` parameter or atleast of what I am reading in the docs? Is there any other way?

Comment: It's available via `self.request`.

Comment: Updated answer, I didn't know that `self` contains a `request` object. I learned another thing. Thanks. :)